# Core PHP or Laravel for more complex projects

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, elasticsearch, cassandra

I am confused about using core php or a framework for my new project. I have done projects in Laravel, Codeignator and some in core php. My project requirements keep confusing me as to which is the better choice. Can anyone suggest best option for me? The following are the functionalities i need to implement in that project:

1) I Should need to upload 30 images at a time. Images with larger size so need to compress the images without losing the clarity and decompress after uploading.

2) I need to integrate lots of API's include Google’s Cloud Vision, MaxMind GeoIP so on..

3) Need to implement two databases; MySQL and Cassandra

4) Need to create user profiles based on there activities inside the website. These content stored in cassandra database

5) Implement Elasticsearch for real time analytics

Can anyone suggest can i go with core php or Laravel?

Comment: Core php? you will waste too much time reinventing the wheel ( which lots of people contributed to make it as good as possible) and its i'm sure your's wont be a better one. go for laravel (there you go this is an opinion there for the question is opinion based)

Comment: Using core PHP is dismissing all the hard work people have done in making things like Laravel to make your life easier. PHP is lucky to have many high quality frameworks with vibrant communities. Pick one that fits your style and needs. Going core PHP is like going camping, it can be educational but it's no way to live.

Answer (score 4):

This is a really broad question, and one that will draw answers based primarily around one's opinion as your project can be achieved with both Core PHP or Laravel.

Given your requirements I would suggest you use Laravel. Starting a project from a framework means that a lot of the initial work has already been done for you and the framework itself will do a lot of the heavy lifting.

The API's, Elasticsearch, and image resizing can all be incorporated through various packages and Laravel's blade engine will help you create consistent views without the repeating your HTML code over and over again.

Using two databases is as simple as setting up two database connections and then ensuring your queries are using the right one.

Remember that Laravel is essentially just Core PHP, it has all just been structured in to a framework - specifically to improve the ease of use and performance.

Comment: *"This is a really broad question, and one that will draw answers based primarily around one's opinion"* Exactly. So why did you choose to answer it, instead of voting to close the question as *too broad* or *primarily opinion-based*?

Comment: @Stijn I did. But after doing so thought I'd do my best to both educate and answer someone who was clearly new to SO.

Comment: OK, your vote must have expired. And while your intentions were good, it's better to not answer this question, because doing so might encourage people to ask such questions again.

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion Laravel is best for your project requirements. Your all functionalities are easily cover in Laravel as compare with core PHP. 
 In your project for further enhancement Laravel is best choice because of there are so many libraries are available for lots of functionalities.
Your project development timing also decrease as compare as core PHP.